# Error in `check_aesthetics using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to do a ggplot with 2 variables Y.
PhyChl has 6 rows and 3 columns (time (x) , phyc (y) and chl (y)) and when I run this command it gives me the following error:

- Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
  ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): y
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Which is the error? Thank you.*emphasized text*

```
ggplot(PhyChl, aes(x=time))+
  geom_line(aes(y = phyc, color = "blue"))+
  geom_line(y = chl, color = "green")
```

Comment: You need `aes()` around `y = chl` in your second `geom_line()`, just like the first one. (But generally you shouldn't put constants like `color = "blue"` inside `aes()`.

Comment: (In case that wasn't clear, change the last line to `geom_line(aes(y = chl), color = "green")`.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you omitted aes() in the second geom_line.
A better approach is to stack the data frame in long format and use the col name as aesthetic.

```
library(tidyr)

ggplot(pivot_longer(PhyChl, c(phyc, chl)), aes(x=time, y=value, color=name ))+
  geom_line()
```